# Laravel join 2 database result set and convert to array of object

Tags: arrays, laravel, object

I'm really new to PHP and Laravel and so far I managed to join query two tables... it looks something like this...

```
$data = DB::table('users')
            ->join('plans', 'plans.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->get();
```

The query above returns something like this..

```
| id | user_id |  name  |  plan_1 | plan_2  | plan_3  |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |    1    |  John  |  resul1 | result2 | result3 |
```

Note that `user_id, plan_1, plan_2, and plan_3` columns are from the `plans table`

Now, what I want is to make the result look like this...

```
$data = [{
    'id' => 1
    'name' => 'John'
    'plan_set' => [{
        'user_id' => 1,
        'plan_1' => 'result1',
        'plan_2' => 'result2',
        'plan_3' => 'result3',
    }]
}]
```

As a newbie on PHP, especially on Laravel, I don't really have an idea on how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... have you thought about using relationships?

Comment: @lagbox What do you mean by it? :) please bare with me T_T

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships and specifically https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many ... but that is using Eloquent Models

Comment: @lagbox I think what you meant was about retrieving the data. however, my concern is about restructuring the retrieved data.

Comment: it would have it nested ... if User has a relationship to Plan and you load it then the User would have a property named 'plans' and in that would be the data for the Plan s (when serialized)

Comment: @lagbox Ohhh i seee, I get it. Thanks man!

Comment: just an option to explore, might make your life easier

Comment: @lagbox Btw, is it possible for more than 2 tables?